# Появляется ошибка: : 'Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.' при вызове метода Change()

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

У меня есть программа с 2-мя формами (программа подключена к базе данных сервера MSql).
В первой форме есть `dataGridView1`, она отображает данные из базы, когда я нажимаю на одну из тех строк в `dataGridView1`, появляется вторая форма с текстовыми полями и все данные, которые были в `dataGridView1`, переносятся на вторую форму в текстовых полях.

Пока все работает нормально. Во второй форме есть возможность изменить данные в текстовом поле, после изменения данных в текстовом поле нужно нажать на кнопку "Изменить" (эта кнопка вызывает метод "Изменить"), а затем кнопку "Сохранить" (эта кнопка вызывает метод `Update`, а в этом методе измененные данные должны попасть в базу), но когда я нажимаю на кнопку "Изменить" появляется ошибка.

Код второй формы, в которой есть кнопка:

```
    private void buttonChange2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
    mainForm.Change();
}
```

код метода `Change`, который находится на главной форме (там, где `dataGridView1`):

```
    public void Change()
{
    Full_Inf_Form Full_Inf_Form = new Full_Inf_Form();

    var selectedRowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex; // <=== NRE exception

    var id = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxID_Inf.Text;
    var name = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxStNa_Inf.Text;
    var lastname = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxLaNa_Inf.Text;
    var patr = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxStPa_Inf.Text;
    var numb = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxNumb_Inf.Text;
    var email = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxEmail_Inf.Text;
    var grup = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxGrup_Inf.Text;
    var spec = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxSpec_Inf.Text;
    var data = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxDataVst_Inf.Text;
    var sypend = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxStSt_Inf.Text;
    var mat = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxBalMat_Inf.Text;
    var ukr = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxBalUkr_Inf.Text;
    var eng = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxBalEng_Inf.Text;
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex].SetValues(id, name, lastname, patr, numb, email, grup, spec, data, sypend, mat, ukr, eng);
        dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[13].Value = RowState.Modified;
    }
}
```

Ошибка появляется в: `var selectedRowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;`.

Это метод, передающий данные из `dataGridView1` в `textBox` второй формы:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    selectedRow = e.RowIndex;

    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        Full_Inf_Form Full_Inf_Form = new Full_Inf_Form();

        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRow];

        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxID_Inf.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxStNa_Inf.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxLaNa_Inf.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxStPa_Inf.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxNumb_Inf.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxEmail_Inf.Text = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxGrup_Inf.Text = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxSpec_Inf.Text = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxDataVst_Inf.Text = row.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxStSt_Inf.Text = row.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxBalMat_Inf.Text = row.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxBalUkr_Inf.Text = row.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxBalEng_Inf.Text = row.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.Show();
    }
}
```

Я попытался перенести метод `Change` из основной формы (где находится `dataGridView1`) во вторую форму, но это не помогло.

Сначала я сделал ту же программу, но текстовые поля и кнопка "Изменить" были в основной программе, то есть была только одна форма и все работало нормально, все данные, которые я изменил в текстовом поле, а затем нажал на кнопка «Изменить», а затем «Сохранить» попала в базу данных, и все заработало нормально.

Но я хотел, чтобы текстовые поля и кнопки «Изменить» и «Сохранить» были в другом виде.

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что CurrentCell в данный момент отсутствует. Проверяйте на null прежде чем использовать. Используйте SelectedCells[0], например, хотя ее тоже надо проверять на количество перед использованием. Иначе будет исключение, если в коллекции 0 элементов.